# ios7 error when submitting an update. this bundle does not support one or more devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, titanium, xcode5

application context: ios7, xcode 5, written with titanium appcelerator (sdk 3.1.3GA), previous version compatibility was as the image says (directly from itunes connect)

[image]

the complete error is

`this bundle does not support one or more devices. supported by the revious app version. your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported. your declare supported device in Xcode with the Targeted Device Family build setting. Refer to QA1623 for additional information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html`

Now. I checked in the building settings as what the message says and the results is attached as images.

[image: project] [image: iphone target][image: ipad target][image: universal target]
as you can see, I should cover all the apple devices (iphone/ipad), but still giving me the same error. anybody knows why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Was your previous version a universal app (supported both iPhone and iPad)?

Comment: yes it was. how can I check that? btw it was writte with titanium too, so the app submission process is the same. @NikosM. see changes

Answer (score 31):

Your app was previously supported iPad too. You cannot drop support for a device family (iPhone or iPad) in an update. Make your app universal in project settings>General tab.

[image]

Comment: this is not working for me. I still have the same error even to set universal device target (for ios target 7.0) to iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for my problem was to simply rebuild the archive from titanium (publish app to apple store) and then archive the app.

I have selected Universal device for universal target.

no issue were found.

so it seems actually there's no problem in the process, but still don't know why there was that device compatibility problem.