# iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to submit my universal iOS 9 apps to Apple (built with Xcode 7 GM) but I receive this error message for the bundle in iTunes Connect, just when I select *Submit for Review*:

> Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown' in bundle 'com.bitscoffee.PhotoMarks.iOS'.

My app has support for Portrait and PortraitUpsideDown orientations but not for the other two.

So is there a workaround for this imposed requirement, or all iOS 9 iPad apps have to have all four orientations?

Answer (score 878, accepted):

iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but your app does not, so you need to opt out of it, just add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s `Info.plist` file and apply the Boolean value `YES`.

Comment: Did anyone got rejected because of this setting? (Requires full screen) According to apple only specific apps can use this setting, such as games.

Comment: @GeorgeSachpatzidis I did not get rejected with that setting.

Comment: Well, my iPad app happily flew through the Validate option in Xcode, but failed to upload to iTunes Connect (with the error you quoted).   So my app never got as far as iTunes !
(Btw, WHY doesn't this error/warning occur earlier in the build process ?!)

Comment: Just to add, Xcode 7.3.1 didn't recognise this "UIRequiresFullScreen" setting - BUT - it has now been added as a checkbox under Targets \ General \ Deployment Info.   "Requires full screen".

Comment: @MikeGledhill, that is a good question, why this error was not identified earlier in the build. That is just stupid to invalidate it at the last step. Publishing on App Store is just a mess, Google Play is way cheaper and cleaner.

Comment: @Eduardo:  Couldn't agree more.  Xcode continues to be a thoroughly horrible development environment (despite Tim Cook praising it and giving away iPads to school  kids to get them interested in using it.)   I remember learning Turbo Pascal 5.5 at school....  Ahhh, happy days...

Comment: This answer works even in Xcode 9.3 inspite of the Requires Fullscreen checkbox checked in the project target screen.

Comment: And the missing of some resolution app icon, why Xcode just tell me at the first moment :(

Comment: Xcode seriously sucks. It's good some things work, like this answer.

Comment: @MikeGledhill is Android Studio better?

Answer (score 648):

In Xcode, check the "Requires Full Screen" checkbox under General > Targets, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Why this option is also available for iPhone-only app?  What will happen if I checked "Requires full screen" for an iPhonely-only app (not iPad-only or universal app)?

Comment: @goodbyeera, looks like you created a topic for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34608826/1956540

Comment: I had to check this box and added a couple of icon images for the iPad. Then upload to App Store was successful.

Comment: In Xcode 12.1 I would just add, that after you've added "Requires Full Screen" make sure you still have both iPhone and iPad checkboxes ticked under General / Deployment info (provided your app supported both before). Otherwise you will get this error when archiving: "This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version. Your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported." See this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925245/ios7-error-when-submitting-an-update-this-bundle-does-not-support-one-or-more-d

Answer (score 84):

I am using Xamarin and there is no available option in the UI to specify "Requires full screen". I, therefore, had to follow @Michael Wang's answer with a slight modification. Here goes:

Open the info.plist file in a text editor and add the lines:

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
```

I tried setting the value to "YES" but it didn't work, which was kind of expected.

In case you are wondering, I placed the above lines below the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations section

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

Hope this helps someone. Credit to Michael.

Comment: I am using Telerik's VS plugin, so this helped me, thank you.

Comment: This is now supported in Xamarin

Answer (score 44):

as Michael said,

Check the "Requires full screen" of the target of xcodeproj, if you don't need to support multitasking.

or Check the following device orientations

- Portrait
- Upside Down
- Landscape Left
- Landscape Right

In this case, we need to support launch storyboard.

Answer (score 11):

Unchecked all Device orientation and **checked only "Requires full screen"**. Its working properly

Comment: Thank you so much..It is worked for me..It is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Go to your project target in Xcode > General > Set "Requires full screen" (under Hide status bar) to true.

Answer (score 4):

As Michael said check the "Requires Full Screen" checkbox under General > Targets

and also delete the 'CFBundleIcons-ipad' from the info.plst

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Portrait (top home button) on the supported interface orientation field of info.plist file in xcode

[image]

Comment: If you remove the two landscape modes (item 2 and item 3) in your supported interface orientations do you not get the same error as OP in the review process? 
At least that's what I got when I tried.