# iOS 9 app Submission issue in MultiTasking require all orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode7

I'm pushing my app to app store using Xcode 7 and my app is universal for iPhone and iPad. But it supports only Portrait and landscape left.

Here's my error:

[image]

How to submit the app with the particular orientation such as Portrait and Landscape left only.

Any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559724/ipad-multitasking-support-requires-these-orientations)

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to enable multi-tasking just disable it by adding `UIRequiresFullScreen` to your `info.plist` and set the boolean value to `YES`

**Or**

Choose your `Target->General->Deployment Info->Enable "Requires Full Screen"` option

[image: Disable Multi-tasking]

Refer [Adopting Multitasking Enhancements on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html)
 for more info