# Updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and Project now has problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, orientation, ios9

So I uploaded my Xcode 6.1 build to iTunes Connect and the app was approved. Now i'm trying to update the app and I updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and Xcode is giving me problems stating:

(For app I used storyboards and Objective-C)

warning: All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen.

warning: A launch storyboard or xib must be provided unless the app requires full screen.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

What's the new supported interface orientation for iOS 9?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your app supports multi tasking you need to support all orientations (Portrait up, Portrait Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right) and a also Launch Screen xib/storyboard.

If you are not interested, you can opt-out by specifying `UIRequiresFullScreen` key in your `info.plist` and setting the boolean value to `YES`. (Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32667003/1104384) for more about this option)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets -> General, Deployment Info and check all for device orientation and the warning will go away e.g. for an iPad only app you have to tick all orientations, in your view controllers then you can override the orientations.