# iOS 9 : Warning "All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen" for universal app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, multitasking

I'm working on an universal app with *all orientations* on iPad and *only portrait* on iPhone. The app works well with split-screen multitasking on iOS 9 compatible iPad, but I have this warning:

```
All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen
```

And my app does not require full screen. It's only limited to portrait on iPhone... Shouldn't it be ok? Is there a way to declare *Requires Full Screen* only on iPhone?

Thanks in advance

By the way I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: this anwser can help u [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058829/updated-to-xcode-7-0-1-and-project-now-has-problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058829/updated-to-xcode-7-0-1-and-project-now-has-problems)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the app to support split-screen on iPad but only portrait on iPhone...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The solution to this is to use "Device Specific Keys":
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW9

Your plist values would therefore look something like:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen~ipad</key>
<false/>
```

When I remove the iPad specific version of the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key, I lose the full split-screen functionality - only "slide over" is available because that doesn't affect my app's use of the full device screen.

The "Device Orientation" checkboxes are for the default plist values. The only way they wouldn't affect the app on the iPad is if there's a more specific value in the plist, therefore a value specifically for iPad.

> When the system searches for a key in your app’s Info.plist file, it chooses the key that is most specific to the current device and platform.

Comment: this is the correct answer - one addition: you may define a reduced set of supported orientations for iphones and allow all for ipads to be compatible with splitview

Answer (score 76):

Set **UIRequiresFullScreen** to **YES** in **Info.plist**.

[image]

Enjoy...!!!

Comment: Nope because I need the split screen to be available. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13):

In fact, it was too easy... That's why I haven't even tried it:

[image: Configuration]

Setting `Portrait` for **Device Orientation** does not impact iPad orientation.

That means that the **Device Orientation** section should be renamed **iPhone Orientation**, indeed, with that configuration, the iPhone only supports `Portrait` and the iPad supports all of them. And the split-screen is still allowed as we have not checked `Requires full screen`.

PS: At least on Xcode 8.3.1, I have not tested it on Xcode 7.x

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? You'll probably find that there's an iPad specific version of the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key in your plist. See my answer for details.

Comment: Indeed, the iPad specific keys are now set directly in the `info.plist`. So even if your solution is more precise, this one is still valid (at least on new projects)

Answer (score 2):

For your case you can use: UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone.

Change UISupportedInterfaceOrientations section in Info.plist to:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

This combination produces no warnings.

Answer (score -5):

Go to Locations tab from the Preferences, locate project's **derived data folder**, and delete files related to the project.