# What is the impact of the "Requires full screen" option in Xcode for an iPhone-only app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7

For an iPad-only app or a universal app, the `"Requires full screen"` option tells Xcode/iOS whether the app supports iPad multitasking feature introduced in iOS 9.  But the `"Requires full screen"` option is also present if it's an iPhone-only app.  In this case, what is the impact of this option?

[image]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is no impact at all. Apple engineers thinks that its not required to hide, or may be Plus phones will get landscape slide over in later iOS versions :)

*From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html):*

To opt out of being eligible to participate in Slide Over and Split View, add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s Info.plist file and apply the Boolean value YES.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, you would need to support both portrait and landscape orientation in your app.If your app is landscape only or portrait only, then the app validation fails with:

**warning: All interface orientations must be supported unless the app requires full screen.**

And as KingofBliss noted, setting this to YES will also stop your app from running in a split view.

It is a useful setting for games that run full screen in landscape only.