# What are the "Requires full screen" and "Supports multiple windows" options in Info.plist for a Xamarin iOS deployment?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know what these options on the iOS deployment for a Xamarin Forms app do? I can't find any place they are documented:

1) Requires full screen
2) Supports multiple windows

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608826/what-is-the-impact-of-the-requires-full-screen-option-in-xcode-for-an-iphone-o
and here https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/multiple-windows/

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful , thanks for marking or voting up when you have time in advance *.^

Answer (score 3):

**Requires Full screen and Supports Multiple Windows**

IOS 9+ supports resizable apps with multi-window support. Unless you are re-writing your app to support multi-window, you will be requiring 'Full screen'. This is a hint to iOS that you do not support multi-window, and basically makes iOS 9+ work like previous versions in this regard.

You can have a look at [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html) .

**In addition** : About Supporting Multiple Windows in iPad

iOS 13 now supports side-by-side windows for the same app on iPad. This enables new experiences and drag-and-drop interactions between windows. This document shows you how to setup your application to support this feature, and introduces these new features.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios13/multi-window-ipad) .