# ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations:

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing an Universal app for Iphone and IPad using xamarin, and I am trying to deploy the app to app store using Xamarin Studio while deployment I am facing the error

> ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires
>   these orientations:
>   'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'.
>   Found
>   'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'
>   in bundle "bundle_Name"

I have spend lots of time on google but I did not get any solution for this how to resolve it using Xamarin Studio.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Edit your plist file from xcode and add this lines

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
```

Or You can do below

[image]

Comment: Solves the problem though its tough to explain how.

Comment: @DeepakGM Yes agree

Comment: Yes this worked, this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728607/1453691 has a screenshot which just takes a second to update and get rid of this error.

Comment: @DeepakGM isn't it obvious? The error is in relation to multitasking. If you declare that you require usage of the full screen, the iPad won't allow multitasking. This plist entry might as well say DisableMultitasking

Comment: still worked after almost 7 years thanks

Answer (score 41):

In Target of Project, tab General, Check at Deployment Info -> Requires full screen. and ReArchive Product.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

- **Xcode 7 N Xcode 8**
- Select Target of  Project  and Select General Tab -> Select Requires
  full screen

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Portrait (top home button) on the supported interface orientation field of info.plist file in xcode

[image]