# I want to release an app but I'm getting the following error message (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait )

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to release an app but I'm getting the following error message:

> Blockquote
> Invalid bundle. The “UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait” orientations were provided for the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations Info.plist key in the [bundle.id] bundle, but you need to include all of the “UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight” orientations to support iPad multitasking. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uisupportedinterfaceorientations.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: check this answer it have same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559724/ipad-multitasking-support-requires-these-orientations

Comment: I have already checked the 'Requires full screen' option, but I'm still getting this error message

Comment: also check this too in your plist file

<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>